# Plot a histogram in pandas columns with a mapping function

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, histogram

l have a `csv` file that l process with `pandas`. The column is called `manual_raw_value` l want to retrieve the unique chars in this column and make a `histogram`.

to retrieve all the uniques values l did the following :

```
 unique_values = set(df.manual_raw_value.apply(list).sum())

{' ',
 '!',
 '"',
 '%',
 '&',
 "'",
 '(',
 ')',
 '*',
 '+',
 ',',
 '-',
 '.',
 '/',
 '0',
 '1',
 '2',
 '3',
 '4',
 '5',
 '6',
 '7',
 '8',
 '9',
 ':',
 '=',
 '>',
 '?',
 '@',
 '_',
 'a',
 'b',
 'c',
 'd',
 'e',
 'f',
 'g',
 'h',
 'i',
 'j',
 'k',
 'l',
 'm',
 'n',
 'o',
 'p',
 'q',
 'r',
 's',
 't',
 'u',
 'v',
 'w',
 'x',
 'y',
 'z'}
```

Here is the data

```
 manual_raw_value
    6,35
    11,68
    VOTRE
    AVEL AR VRO
    2292
    questions.
    nb
    les
    937,99
    à
    et
    TTC
    1
    620
    Echéance
    vos
    ROB21
    Pièce
    AGRIAL
    désignation
    des
    taux
    13s
    2
    par
    le
    mois,
    32
    21/07/2016
    FR
    au
    0
    téléphonique
    BROYEUR
    et
    ST
    TVA
    de
    des
    ECHEANCIER
    à
    ne
    lieu
    481,67
    N°0016
    de
    ministère
    de
    20/11/2015
    Si
    vous
    59
    cas
    EUR
    3.19
    2
    contrôle
    assurances
    BAS
    et
    4423873
    renseignements
    6104219
    C9DECOMPTEDIVERS
    6635
    DE
    10825
```

Now, since l have the `unique values`  l want to make a histgram.
Here is what l've tried

```
  import pandas as pd
    def find_group(val):
        unique_values = set(df.manual_raw_value.apply(list).sum())
        for unique in unique_values:
            # get the number of occurence of all the unique values
            # then make a histogram



    df = pd.read_csv('words.csv',sep=',')
    df = df.astype(str)
    df.manual_raw_value=df.manual_raw_value.str.lower()
    df.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group)
    df.manual_raw_value.apply(find_group).value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

The unique values are those returned by the function 
`unique_values = set(df.manual_raw_value.apply(list).sum())` which are `{' ', '!', '"', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', '0', '1', .....` and so on .
 Now look for instance at the two values of manual `row values : 6,35 11,68` then we can say `1 appears twice 6 twice ',' twice 3 one time 5 one time`

**Edit-1**
l tried this code to make a histogram of the numbre of occurence of `alpha cells`, `alpahnumeric` cells and `special char cells`

```
def find_group(val):
    val = str(val)
    if val.isalpha():
        return 'Alpha'
    elif val.isalnum and any(c.isalpha() for c in val):
        return 'Alphanumeric'
    else:
        return 'Special'

df.Column_values.apply(find_group)
df.Column_values.apply(find_group).value_counts().plot(kind='bar')
```

Now l want to make a histogram at a character level :

- get  the unique characters in the column by looping through each cell. **(It's done)**
- Count the number of occurrence of these characters in all the cells and make a histogram . **# l get stucked at it**
  -Once

**Edit-2**
Let's take a practical example. Let's say my column is called `Column_value`

```
 Column_value
    hello
    good
    morning
    how 
    are 
    you
```

1-at each row  l compute the number of occurrence of each character

```
hello :  h=1 l=2 o=1 e=1
good :   g=1 o=2 d=1
morning : m=1 o=1 r=1 n=2 g=1
how: h=1 o=1 w=1 
are : a=1 r=1 e=1
you: y=1 o=1 u=1
```

2- make a sum to get the number of of occurrence of each character in all rows

```
h=1+1=2
l=2
o=2+1+1+1=5
e=1+1=2
g=1
d=1
```

and so on
 now , make a histogram of 
h=2 , l=2 , o=5, e=2, g=1, d=1

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, please see my updates. l want to count the number of occurence of each character in that column by looping through the cells then make a histogram

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, please see update 2 for a practical example

Comment: @vincent75 I guess you dont want histogram of unique values, then histogram would always be 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

taking example from OP.

```
import pandas as pd
words=["hello","good","morning","how","are","you"]
df=pd.DataFrame(words,columns=['words'])

pd.Series(list(df.words.str.cat())).value_counts().plot(kind="bar")
```

[image]
after df.words.str.cat(), one could also use regex to filter the characters

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in histogram function on pandas Series. for example:

```
df['col'] = [1,1,1,2,3,4,4]
df.col.hist()
```

will return a histogram of each value occurrence.
But, since non-numerical values might cause there bugs you can also use `value_counts` and `plot(kind='bar')` methods.

```
df.col.value_counts()
```

will return **Series** with value as an index and count as a value.

Then you can just run `plot` to show the histogram:

```
df.col.value_counts().plot(kind = 'bar')
```

Comment: please see edit 2 and 1. l'm looking for a histogram that counts the number of occurence of  every character in all the strings

Comment: The update says that the 1st problem (single char per cell) is solved, so I provided solution from there. If you have troubles with splitting the chars try first split to columns by char and then use ``pandas.melt`` [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.melt.html)